# Creating a callable function in a VSTO office addin - COMAddIns.Object is always Nothing

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com, vsto

I want to be able to call a function in a VSTO addin from an Excel VBA macro. To test the principle I have the following C# code.

```
namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IThisAddIn
    {
        String GetText();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public partial class ThisAddIn : IThisAddIn
    {    
        public String GetText()
        {
            return "Now is the winter of dicontent made glorius summer by this son of York";
        }       
    }
}
```

And I have the following VBA script

```
Public Sub RunTest()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim AddInList As Object
    Dim ExcelAddIn1 As COMAddIn
    Dim ThisAddIn As Object

    Set ExcelAddIn1 = Application.COMAddIns("ExcelAddIn1")

    txt = ExcelAddIn1.Object.GetText()
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = txt
End Sub
```

ExcelAddIn1.Object = Nothing

The Microsoft walkthrough at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba seems to be a bit muddled.

I think I might need to add `RequestComAddInAutomationService` but it doesn't work as described in the walkthrough. When I try to instantiate an instance of my class within `RequestComAddInAutomationService` I get the error basically telling me I need to supply an ApplicationFactory and IServiceProvider as parameters.

```
private ThisAddIn utilities;

protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
{
    if (utilities == null)
       utilities = new ThisAddIn();

    return utilities;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class derived from `IThisAddIn` must be different of the main vsto class (as in the microsoft example) so just replace your code with:

```
  [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IComAddIn
    {
        String GetText();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public  class AddInUtilities : IComAddIn
    {
        public String GetText()
        {
            return "Now is the winter of dicontent made glorius summer by this son of York";
        }
    }
```

in vsto:

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private AddInUtilities utilities;

        protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
        {
            if (utilities == null)
                utilities = new AddInUtilities();

            return utilities;
        }
  ....
```

Also when you call `Application.COMAddIns` in VBA, be sure that the string you give as argument correspond to the `AssemblyTitle` of your vsto project.

PS there is no need to "register for com interop".

Comment: That seems like it should be the right answer. Everything is now compiling and running nicely, but ExcelAddIn1.Object is still Nothing. The string argument to COMAddIns in VBA is right - otherwise it would fall at that point. Must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Maybe the `Set` keyword in VBA ?  `Set MyNoNMissingObject = ExcelAddIn1.Object` then `MyNoNMissingObject.GetText()`

Comment: Yep - tried that. Also added `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]` to the interface as suggested by [Andrew Whitechapel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice/)

Comment: Aha! Just noticed my class declaration wasn't marked as public. ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual doesn't seem to make any difference.